# Whats the Powershell equivalent of the redirect input operator

Tags: powershell

In Bash, I can redirect a file to a `nc` process like this:

```
user@host:~$ nc -nv 10.11.0.22 4444 < /some/directory/file.txt
```

What's the Powershell equivalent of this?

Comment: I commend to your attention [Microsoft Learn on PowerShell Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: @JeffZeitlin That link doesn't mention input.

Comment: Lots of questions like this all over StackExchange, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447598/redirecting-standard-input-output-in-windows-powershell - `<` isn't available, but there are other simple ways to process input, e.g. pipes.

Comment: @DavidPostill - You're correct; I should also have added a reference to [Microsoft Learn on the PowerShell Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.3), which (together) should have provided the clues that the querent needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What's the Powershell equivalent of the redirect input operator

You can't use `<` in PowerShell. Instead use `|`:

```
Get-Content /some/directory/file.txt | nc -nv 10.11.0.22 4444
```